# How to either skip lines or check type of data within single construction line when processing csv input into Python dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

My input is a .csv file that happens to have headers.

I want to use a concise line, like this:

```
mydict = {custID:[parser.parse(str(date)), amount] 
          for transID, custID, amount, date in reader}
```

to create a dictionary from the input. However, the data isn't perfectly "clean". I want to check that each row of data is the sort of data that I want the dictionary to map.

Something like:

```
mydict = {if custID is type int custID:[parser.parse(str(date)), amount] 
          for transID, custID, amount, date in reader}
```

would be a nice fix, but, alas, it does not work.

Any suggestions that keep the short dictionary constructor while facilitating input processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track and filtering with dictionary comprehension should work here:

```
mydict = {custID: [parser.parse(str(date)), amount]
          for transID, custID, amount, date in reader
          if isinstance(custID, int)}
```

In this case, you would though silently ignore rows where `custID` is not of an integer type.

Plus, things would go wrong if `custID` is not unique. If `custID`s could repeat, you might want to switch to a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) collection, collecting date+amount pairs grouped by `custID`.

Answer (score 2):

For a similar task, I've personally used [`CsvSchema` third-party package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CsvSchema/) - you can define what types in csv columns are you expecting, extra validation rules:

> CsvSchema is easy to use module designed to make CSV file checking
>   easier. It allows to create more complex validation rules faster
>   thanks to some predefined building blocks.

In your case, here is an example CSV structure class you may start with:

```
from datetime import datetime

from csv_schema.structure.base import BaseCsvStructure
from csv_schema.columns.base import BaseColumn
from csv_schema.exceptions import ImproperValueException
from csv_schema.columns import IntColumn, DecimalColumn, StringColumn


class DateColumn(BaseColumn):
    def convert(self, raw_val):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(raw_val, '%Y-%m-%d') if raw_val else None
        except ValueError:
            raise ImproperValueException('Invalid date format')


class MyCsvStructure(BaseCsvStructure):
    transID = IntColumn(max_length=10)
    custID = IntColumn(max_length=10)
    amount = DecimalColumn(blank=True, fraction_digits=2)
    date = DateColumn(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

Comment: Really hoping for a concise solution, but thanks for this. I could expand the iteration through the .csv file and check types if I wanted to, but trying to keep it tight!

Comment: @d0rmLife got it. I personally really liked this kind of modeling with a "schema" defined over the CSV file. In my case, I had to validate the input file from lots of different perspectives and having a separately defined schema with custom (sometimes complex) rules helped me to solve it in a clean way and in a modular manner. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there are definitely cases when broader verification is necessary, and sometimes that displays best in larger code blocks. For my application, though, just hoping for something brief and tight. Upvoted your answer anyways because it provides a useful solution!